# What is HHOJSID URI path parameter used for?

Tags: url

I was testing a site with cookies disabled and I noticed HHOJSID parameter in URL path.
It could be a session ID encoded in URL like jsessionid for J2EE web applications.
I searched Google and found a lot of examples but no technical description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this parameter seems to appear exclusively in URLs for HP's Home and Home Office online store, I suggest it stands for "Home and Home Office Java Session ID".

I'm sure you're right when you say it's a URL-based session ID - it's just that HP have modified its name for their online store.

Comment: It makes sense, I did not notice that it appeared only on HP sites. Thanks